# How correctly execute sql query (node.js + express)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

On database I have two tables: users which contains all the user registration details and friends which contains user friends relation data (friend_one, friend_two are the FOREIGN KEYs to references users.user_id), status (0 - expectation, 1 - denied, 2 - accepted) and timestamp. friend_one - is always initiator of friendship. Girls can add to friends only boy and boys can add only girls. So when i try get amount of friends of user - boy with id `5` for example :
[image]

```
exports.amountOfFriends = function (req, res) {
    var user =  req.session.user,
    userId = req.session.session_id;
    if(userId == null){
       res.redirect("/login");
       return;
    }
   let sql = `SELECT COUNT(*) myCount FROM friends WHERE status = ? AND friends_one =? OR friends_two =? `;
   let post = [2, userId, userId];
    connection.query(sql, post, (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        res.json(result);
        console.log(result[0].myCount);

    });

};
```

I get value - 2. But correct value is 3. Because user with id 5 has three friends. Please help me fix this problem. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you just miss bracket

Comment: when I add bracket I get value zero(

Comment: Can you run below ans to your mysql ?

Comment: Yes, and I still get zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You neeed  a `()`   around the twor OR condition

```
 `SELECT COUNT(*) myCount FROM friends
   WHERE status = ? AND ( friends_one =? OR friends_two =?) `;
```

Comment: I check, and I still get zero(

Comment: which data  type are the columns status, friend_one, friend_two ..??

Comment: @scaisEdge, friend_one and friend two is integer, status is ENUM ('0','1','2')

Comment: try exit and reenter in your sql/IDE

Comment: i have tested  the code in my db and work correctly  .. just for test try execute  the equivalente query 
      `SELECT COUNT(*) myCount FROM friends
          WHERE ( status = 2 AND friends_one =5)  OR (  status = 2 AND friends_two 5) `;

Comment: @scaisEdge,i don't know why, but i again get zero(

Comment: are you sure you are connected  related  to the correct data source??  . seems that your table have not the expected  data

Comment: @scaisEdge, thank you for your help, I have found my mistake, I just must write WHERE status = '2', instead of WHERE status = 2.

Comment: very well  so the asnwer is correct  .. good job  .. and also the comments are appropriate